# Java 11 migration error 'package com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations is not visible'

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, xpath

I am migrating code from Java 8 to Java 11 and coming across this build failure error:

```
package com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations is not visible
(package com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations is declared in module java.xml, which does not export it)
```

I tried looking at the other proposed solutions on this:

1. [Problems with importing com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230554/problems-with-importing-com-sun-org-apache-xpath-internal-operations) and
2. https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1110036/

but neither are working for me
ie: Using the 2nd proposed solution, added the exclusion but still getting a build failure

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Any help or pointers on how I can fix this, either in the pom or otherwise? Thanks

Comment: The error message says that the class comes from module `java.xml`, which is part of JSE. That means you cannot exclude it. Since Java 9 introduced the module system, you don't get access to internal classes anymore. That's part of the purpose of the module system - better encapsulation. If you're using is using classes from this package, you've been going against Oracle's (and even Sun's) advise all this time.

Comment: @RobSpoor Thanks for your response. Currently all the code is in Java 8 and we are migrating it to Java 11. So, I was hoping there would be an 'easy' fix, via pom or somewhere, instead of code changes where the import is used and other places in code where those functions/methods are called.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Besides shielding access to internal packages, the module system also disallows classes from the same package to be located in two different location (JRE, JAR files). That means that even if you could find a JAR file with classes from this package, the module system would prevent you from using those classes. The only real solution is to not use those classes, which means refactoring code.